# Compiled .dll files requiring msvcr100.dll to load

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dependencies, libraries

I have a dll file compiled in MSVC++ 2010. It doesn't require any other extra library, yet only half of its users can load it because some are missing msvcr100.dll. Looking at the dependencies, it is requiring some basic functions like memcpy free malloc, though I thought those were standard C runtime functions. The code generation setting is set to "Multi-Threaded /MT" in the properties. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was deleting the dll from Windwos\System32 and reinstalling the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84&displaylang=en

Comment: Surely not for a dll file that only uses standard C libraries?

Comment: That *is* the standard C library (when linked dynamically).  I read through [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx), but it sounds like using /mt is meant to *not* trigger the dynamic link, so I'm not sure what would be causing it.