# Error "msvcr100.dll" (only on Windows 7 & Vista) even AFTER statically linking (/MT)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a simple dll that is being injected into a target process using MS detours.  The process doing the injecting is C# .net application.

Both the DLL and the detours library have been statically linked (/MT option).

However when I try to inject the dll into a target program on a client's machine I get error **"msvcr100.dll" is missing"** error.  Now I open the dll w/ depends and there is no dependency on "msvcr100.dll".

Even weirder this issue only happens when the client is vista x64 or windows 7 x64.  The dll is successfully injected on windows xp x32 and windows 7 x32 systems.

Any ideas on what bug in visual studio is indicating a dependency on a library not being used?

On edit:
Looks like someone else had the same issue ... never resolved.
[Compiled .dll files requiring msvcr100.dll to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188716/compiled-dll-files-requiring-msvcr100-dll-to-load)

For the record installing Visual studio 2010 C++ redistributable on client machine "solves" the issue however I hoped to avoid that dependency by statically linking.

Comment: Do you have a program that uses the DLL without the detours/process injection? If so, does that program have the same issue?

Comment: Well, what dependency does the detours.lib you use have?  It only takes one.

Comment: I rebuilt detours from source w /MT flag.  it "should" have no dependencies .... right?  Also remember the applications works w/o any issues (no "missing mscvr100.dll" error") on Windows XP  machine w/o any libraries installed (clean OS install)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I never did discover exactly what the issue is but on a hunch I tried running the application (exact same build w/ mscvr100.dll error) on another Windows 7 machine and it worked fine.

I reinstalled Windows 7 on the "problem" machine and the same build works fine without error.  In my google searching I came across a report of another person having this issue after uninstalling Visual Studio.  I know for a fact that Visual Studio was installed on the "problem" Windows 7 machine at one time and was currently uninstalled.

If this happens to someone else I would recommend try running the binary on a machine that has never had visual studio installed.  If it works without issue then likely there is some issue related to VS uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to figure out what's going on my attaching (pre-injection) the cdb debugger to the process on a machine where `msvcr100.dll` is loaded (with the DLL installed).  Use the

```
sxe ld:msvcr100
```

command to break when that DLL is loaded (I'm not 100% sure if that's the exactly correct syntax).  Once it's loaded, you might be able to figure out why by looking at the call stack. If not, try setting a breakpoint on everything in that module:

```
bm msvcr100!*
```

and see who's calling it.  That should give you a really good idea why it's being loaded.

Comment: I'll give you a +1 but I wasn't able to try your solution.  When I ran it on another Windows 7 machine (just to test before installing C++ runtime it worked (see my answer above).